# Attempting to get rid of binary operator expected error when opening a terminal session

Tags: binary, operator-keyword

Every time I begin a new terminal session on my Mac, I receive the following error messages:

-bash: [: /Users/angelobrown/wdi/exercises/test_ossicle/google-cloud-sdk: binary operator expected
-bash: [: /Users/angelobrown/wdi/exercises/test_ossicle/google-cloud-sdk: binary operator expected

Can anyone tell me how to fix this so that I no longer experience these messages when beginning a new terminal session?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the problem is something unquoted inside the file ~/.bashrc.
This file is executed when bash is opened.
So you should open `nano ~/.bashrc` and search for directories with folder name spaced.
In my case, my Windows username is `name lastname`, so I justed quoted it in the file.
Ex:
`/mnt/c/users/Foo Bar/something` change to `'/mnt/c/users/Foo Bar/something'`